# Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: multithreading, swing, nullpointerexception

i have a problem with this exception.
I'm trying to make a function to display data from database on a table, every keystroke i made at jtextfield. So its like the table automatically refreshed with new data everytime i type in the jtextfield.

Here's the code :

First i have this variable :

```
private Statement stmt;
List<Barang> dataSBarang =new LinkedList();
boolean searchBarang=true;
Searching sBarang;
```

And this is how i call the function :

```
private void inputkodeTFMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                         
    sBarang = new Searching( stmt, dataSBarang, modelDetail, tabelDetailBarang, inputkodeTF, searchBarang);
    sBarang.start();
}
```

And this is the Searching Object

```
public class Searching extends Thread{
private Statement stmt;
private List<Barang> dataBarang;
private JTable jTabelBarang;
private JTextField tf;
private boolean cari;
private DefaultTableModel modelBarang;

public Searching(Statement stmt, List<Barang> dataBarang, DefaultTableModel tm, JTable jTabelBarang, JTextField tf, boolean cari){
   this.stmt=stmt;
   this.dataBarang=dataBarang;
   this.modelBarang=tm;
   this.jTabelBarang=jTabelBarang;
   this.tf=tf;
   this.cari=cari;

}


@Override
public void run(){
    String temp="";
    while(cari==true){
    //System.out.println("jalan");
    try{
        String masukan = tf.getText();
        System.out.println(masukan);
    if(!masukan.equals("")&&!masukan.equals(temp)){
        clearTableBarang();
        //System.out.println("Mencari "+ masukan);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select kode_barang, nama_barang, jumlah_stok, " +
            "minimal_stok, harga_jual, deskripsi_barang from BARANG WHERE (kode_barang LIKE " +
            "'"+masukan+"%')");
        System.out.println(rs);

        while(rs.next()){
            String kode_barang = rs.getString ("kode_barang");
            String nama_barang = rs.getString ("nama_barang");
            int jumlah_stok = rs.getInt("jumlah_stok");
            int minimal_stok = rs.getInt("minimal_stok");
            int harga_jual = rs.getInt("harga_jual");
            String deskripsi_barang = rs.getString ("deskripsi_barang");
            //System.out.println(kode_barang+" "+deskripsi_barang);

            dataBarang.add(new Barang(kode_barang,nama_barang,jumlah_stok,minimal_stok,harga_jual,deskripsi_barang));

            ((DefaultTableModel) jTabelBarang.getModel()).insertRow(jTabelBarang.getRowCount(), new Object[]{kode_barang, nama_barang, jumlah_stok, minimal_stok, harga_jual, deskripsi_barang});



        }
        temp = masukan;
    }
    else if(masukan.equals("")&&!masukan.equals(temp)) {
        clearTableBarang();
        showTableBarang();
        temp = masukan;
    }
    } catch(SQLException s){s.printStackTrace();}
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException s){s.printStackTrace();}
    try {
        sleep(500);

} catch(InterruptedException e){}

    }
}
public void clearTableBarang(){
    int numrows = modelBarang.getRowCount();
    for(int i = numrows - 1; i >=0; i--){
        modelBarang.removeRow(i);
    }

    dataBarang.clear();


}
public void showTableBarang(){
    try{
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select kode_barang, nama_barang, jumlah_stok, minimal_stok, harga_jual, deskripsi_barang from barang");
    while(rs.next()){
            String kode_barang = rs.getString ("kode_barang");
            String nama_barang = rs.getString ("nama_barang");
            int jumlah_stok = rs.getInt("jumlah_stok");
            int minimal_stok = rs.getInt("minimal_stok");
            int harga_jual = rs.getInt("harga_jual");
            String deskripsi_barang = rs.getString ("deskripsi_barang");
            //System.out.println(kode_barang+" "+deskripsi_barang);

            dataBarang.add(new Barang(kode_barang,nama_barang,jumlah_stok,minimal_stok,harga_jual,deskripsi_barang));

            ((DefaultTableModel)jTabelBarang.getModel()).insertRow(jTabelBarang.getRowCount(), new Object[]{kode_barang, nama_barang, jumlah_stok, minimal_stok, harga_jual, deskripsi_barang});

    }
    } catch(SQLException s){s.printStackTrace();}
}
public void delay(){
    try {
        sleep(1000000000);

} catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
```

}

This is the error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mypkg.Searching.run(Searching.java:47)
```

FYI : Line 47 is pointing to

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select kode_barang, nama_barang, jumlah_stok, " +
"minimal_stok, harga_jual, deskripsi_barang from BARANG WHERE (kode_barang LIKE " +
"'"+masukan+"%')");
```

Please help me solve the problem. Thank you very much. :D

Comment: Please tell us in which line NPE manifests itself. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: 1. Where is line 47? 2. Don't update gui objects outside the EDT.

Comment: Im sry im noob, what is NPE ?

Comment: @radik short for NullPointerException

Comment: Ah the NPE point to the first ResultSet i made
I tried to print the 'masukan' and it showed, but when i tried to print the rs, it didnt show

Comment: @radik Of course ... even if `masukan` is `null` you wouldn't get a NPE. And since you get an NPE, `rs` is never assigned a value. The only variable that can cause the NPE in that line is `stmt` which will be `null`, as I posted in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullPointerException`s are the most easy ones to fix with a debugger. Just place a breakpoint on that line and see what is `null`.

If the line you posted is correct, you do not even need a debugger since the only thing that can throw the exception is `stmt` which will be `null`.

*Note:*

- It is a good thing to run your DB query in a separate `Thread` to avoid blocking the UI. However, in your case you are updating the UI from that `Thread` which is not allowed and will cause weird issues. All Swing components must be accessed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Consult the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information
- I do hope you are not starting up a separate `Thread` on each keystroke in the textfield as you indicated in your question. Looking at the code in the `Thread`, you remove all elements from the table and then re-add rows. So if a users types in 5 characters at a normal typing speed, you will launch 5 threads which most likely run all at the same time (since a DB connection might not be that fast if your network is lagging). That means that with your current code 5 Threads are, *at the same time*, removing the table model and adding rows. Even if you put all the Swing code on the EDT (see my first point), you still end up with 5 threads posting runnables on the EDT messing with your table model. I do not know what the resulting table model will be, but probably not what you want

Comment: Ooh i get it, thx for you suggestion.
I will try to find another way to do this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you Robin, yea i checked it and, stmt is null @@
i forgot to change it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `stmt` is null.

You declare it here:

```
private Statement stmt;
List<Barang> dataSBarang =new LinkedList();
boolean searchBarang=true;
Searching sBarang;
```

But I don't see any initialization code anywhere, so most likely it remains null for this method call:

```
private void inputkodeTFMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                         
    sBarang = new Searching( stmt, dataSBarang, modelDetail, tabelDetailBarang, inputkodeTF, searchBarang);
    sBarang.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tudor. I checked it and now its better. Thank you so much.